# How to solve: $\frac{3·x-5}{8·x-2}<6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to solve $\frac{3x-5}{8x-2}<6$ ?

I'm not sure which first step to take. I mean if I multiply both sides by $8x-2$ then I'm not sure if the sign would switch, as this could be positive or negative depending on $x$.

Comment: Make a case distinction.

Comment: Look at where the denominator is $<0,=0, >0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

You can't multiply by $8x-2$ without discuss on its sign. The best way to answer the question is:

$$\frac{3x-5}{8x-2}<6\iff\frac{3x-5}{8x-2}-6=\frac{-45x+7}{8x-2}<0$$
and now draw a signs table for this quotient.

**Edit** The sign table is
[image]

so the answer is $$\left(-\infty,\frac7{45}\right)\cup \left(\frac14,+\infty\right)$$

Comment: The other answer shows the way to solve the problem of multiplying: multiply by a non-negative factor! Much faster than checking signs cases...

Comment: The other answer is similar and he should reason on the sign of each factor!

Comment: Why "should" he reason about those signs beyond the fact that knowing that multiplying an inequality by a non-negative factor leaves the inequality sign steady, @user63181 ?

Comment: In what cases we have $ab>0$? Didn't you think on the sign of $a$ and $b$? Have you an alternative method?

Comment: Just read lab's answer, @user : there, he multiplies by $\;a^2\;$ and ....that's it.

Comment: @DonAntonio while I agree that in this case lab's answer is clever and straightforward, it is not as clear in the case of a nonstrict inequality. I feel that this answer is better from an educational standpoint in a precalculus class.

Comment: @Joel, I can't see why it wouldn't work as smoothly as in this case with *any* kind of inequalities. And I think the most beautiful and educative method is the remarking the interaction between algebra and geometry. Matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @Joel Multiplication or division is similar on the signs table: $-\times +=\frac{-}{+}=-$

Comment: I understand all of this. And I think lab's answer is actually very good. I just know that when you introduce new methods when students are still wrapping their heads around the old ones, that it can introduce confusion. Much later, I would introduce other methods. That is when students have a firm grasp on the old method. It is a matter of taste really.

Answer (score 14):

Check if the denominator $=0$

Otherwise,

$$\frac{3x-5}{8x-2}<6\iff \frac{3x-5}{8x-2}-6<0\iff\frac{45x-7}{8x-2}>0\iff (45x-7)(8x-2)>0$$

as for real $x,(8x-2)^2>0$

$$\implies\left(x-\frac7{45}\right)\left(x-\frac28\right)>0$$

If $\displaystyle(x-a)(x-b)>0,$ where $a<b$ can you prove that either $x<a$ or $x>b$ for real $a,b$

Comment: Except for $x={1 \over 4}$?

Comment: The easiest, fastest and simplest way +1

Comment: Never learned anything like this. Is this the "standard" way to solve those kind of inequalities ?

Comment: In fact @copper.hat, $\;x=\frac14\;$ doesn't satisfay the rightmost, last inequality....but I agree: it *should* be clearly stated from the beginning what the definition set is (as, for example, if the inequality was weak then...)

Comment: @90intuition, it is probably the best, easiest way. Observe the last inequality is reached after multiplying by $\;(8x-2)^2\;$ , which is *always* non-negative and thus we have no problems with the inequality sign.

Comment: I would stop at $\frac{45x-7}{8x-2}>0$, or add a step $\frac{x-\frac7{45}}{x-\frac14}>0$ and conclude that the numerator and denominator must be both strictly positive or negative.

Comment: @90intuition This is a nice and concise way. However, when it comes to label 'standard' I would plead for the answer of user63181.

Comment: Why not doing the last step and using the surely well-known and easy geometric intuition from parabolas, @YvesDaoust ? BTW, the above is the standard way these things are taught here (Israel).

Comment: @drhab, perhaps the standard label should be seen as a poorly thought/developed way to teach this stuff in high school...? My opinion merely, nothing else.

Comment: @Don: the way I was taught, I would have got rid of the denominator (keeping the sign in mind), and solved the linear inequality.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, that requires from you to do cases:  $\;(1)\;\;8x-2>0\;,\;\;(2)\;\;8x-2<0\;$ . In the above we save this *and then* use what we know (hopefully) already about parabolas.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think the formulation is a little ambiguous but long established. I think (in this case) that ${1 \over 4}$ should automatically be excluded even if it satisfied the 'relaxed' equation.

Comment: @copper.hat, I agree with you. In fact, high school kids here are usually *required* to explicitly write down the definition domain of the equation after, if needed, simplifying in a basic way numerators and denominators.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply both sides of $\frac{3x-5}{8x-2}<6$ by $(8x-2)^2$ will make you free from the worry (if the sign would switch).

Comment: This is exactly the same method shown in lab's answer 17 minutes ago...

Comment: @DonAntonio Not quite. He did that after moving terms and simplifications. I suggest performing it right at the beginning.

Comment: Mick, and that's an improvement on something that gives **exactly** the same because...?

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP says “…not sure which first step to take. ……”; and “not sure if the sign would switch”. I am showing him the worry-free initial step. After that, it is a go with full-throttle.

Comment: @DonAntonio Because the 'annoying' denominator is gone after the *first* step allready? The sooner the worry of the student is gone, the better, I would say.

Comment: @drhab, I don't see that as an advantage at all in general if, for example, the right side is something less nice than a constant, and also because in order to have the definition domain is usually necessary *first* to simplify somehow numerators and denominators, something that could be easily overlooked with this method...but I guess it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $8x-2>0$ (i.e. $x>\frac14$) and multiply both sides: $3x-5<48x-12$, or $x>\frac7{45}$.

Symmetrically, when $x<\frac14$ you get $x<\frac7{45}$.

Combined, $x>\frac14\lor x<\frac7{45}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3x-5}{8x-2}<6\iff\frac{3x-5}{8x-2}-6<0\iff\frac{3x-5-48x+12}{8x-2}<0\iff$$ 
$$\iff\frac{7-45x}{2(4x-1)}<0\iff\frac{7-45x}{4x-1}<0\iff$$
$$\left(7-45x>0\text{and}4x-1<0\iff x<\frac{7}{45}\text{and} x<\frac{1}{4}\iff x<\frac{1}{4}\right)$$
or
$$\left(7-45x<0\text{and}4x-1>0\iff x>\frac{7}{45}\text{and} x>\frac{1}{4}\iff x>\frac{7}{45}\right)\iff$$
$$\iff x\in\mathbb R-\ [1/4,7/45\ ]$$