# How to solve:$\frac{3}{x-5}< \frac{7}{x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to solve: $\dfrac{3}{x-5}< \dfrac{7}{x-2}$

Any smart ideas for this one ?

Could I rewrite this as $\dfrac{x-5}{3}> \dfrac{x-2}{7}$ ?

Comment: Say, for example $ \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{2}$, then by taking the reciprocal the inequality changes and becomes $3>2$. Can you simplify the inequality in your question now ?

Comment: Ah that is smart.

Comment: This is essentially identical to the [last question you asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832961/how-to-solve-frac3-x-58-x-26); the method is always the same.

Comment: Are you sure ? I think panda bear solutions is very cool

Comment: No, you can't always do that...... It was just some food for thought.

Comment: Sadly, @PandaBear's solution doesn't always work. After all, $-\frac12<\frac12,$ but if we take the reciprocal and reverse the inequality, we get the false statement $-2>2.$

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes you right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguably, the simplest way to go is to multiply both sides of the inequality by $(x-5)(x-2)$ to clear the denominators, but *we have to be careful*! If $2<x<5,$ then this quantity will be negative, and so multiplication will reverse the inequality's direction. If $x<2$ or $x>5,$ it will be positive, and the direction of the inequality will stay the same. Of course, the inequality makes no sense if $x=2$ or $x=5,$ so the previous cases cover the gamut, and we will need to deal with them separately.

Let's suppose first that $x<2$ or $x>5.$ Multiplying on both sides and distributing gives us $3x-6<7x-35,$ which gives us $x>\frac{29}4=7.25,$ and so (under our assumptions) we see that $x>\frac{29}4.$

Now, let's suppose that $2<x<5,$ so that multiplication gives us $3x-6>7x-35,$ so that $x<\frac{29}4,$ and so (under our assumptions) we see that $2<x<5.$

So, the inequality holds when $2<x<5$ or $x>\frac{29}4.$

Comment: Could I use your answer in a solution manual that I'm writing ?

Comment: I like your writing style.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general approach:

Move both fractions to the left-hand side:

$\frac{3(x-2)-7(x-5)}{(x-5)(x-2)}<0$

After simplification:
$\frac{29-4x}{(x-5)(x-2)}<0$

This reduces the problem to figuring out when the signs of the numerator and denominator are opposite. Can you solve the problem now?

Comment: I think I can, but I wonder if I could simplify this as : $\dfrac{x-5}{3}> \dfrac{x-2}{7}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
\begin{align}
\frac3{x-5}&<\frac7{x-2}\\
\frac3{x-5}-\frac7{x-2}&<0\\
\frac{3(x-2)-7(x-5)}{(x-5)(x-2)}&<0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{3}{x - 5 }$ < $\dfrac{7}{x - 2}$ $or$,${3}(x - 2)$ < ${7}(x - 5)$ $or$,$3x -6$ $<$ $7x - 35$ or,$4x$>$35 - 6$ or,$x$ >$\dfrac {29}{4}$.Therefore $x$ is greater than $7.25$.Now the solution set of $x$ can be found out by drawing the number line.
Ur operation is correct.When u multiply negative no on both sides or reciprocate it u ve to change the inequality sign.